# Save large entities and children with entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to update an entity that has two children which also has two children that both are dependent on both parents.

```
                            Job(PK: Jobid)
       Holes(PK: Holeid, FK: Jobid) / Orders(PK: Orderid, FK: Jobid)
Tools(PK: Toolid, FK: Holeid, FK: Orderid) / ToolHoles(PK: Holeid, Orderid)
```

Tools also has 7 children that inherit from it.

The job will already exist on save. The job may or may not already contain 1 or more of each child entity.

I need to be able to save all this information in one transaction so that partial info is not saved to the database.

My current attempt has been to build up the Job entity with all the relevant information and call SaveChanges. If I'm adding new entities, keys will have to be generated on save for all but Jobid. Is what I'm trying to accomplish even possible?

Comment: If you're asking "Does EF keep track of the new keys and update the children appropriately", then the answer is "Yes"

Comment: Even if the children will get new keys from both parents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making some assumptions here, let me know if I'm off base.  If your scenario looks like the below, then you should be fine.

```
var myHoles = new Holes();
var myOrders = new Orders();
var myTools = new Tools();
var myToolHoles = new ToolHoles();

myJob.Holes.Add(myHoles);  //myJob already exists
myJob.Orders.Add(myOrders);

myHoles.Tools.Add(myTools);
myOrders.Tools.Add(myTools);

myHoles.ToolHoles.Add(myToolHoles);
myOrders.ToolHoles.Add(myToolHoles);

db.SaveChanges();
```

You say "one transaction" but the reality is that several transactions take place.

- `myHoles` and `myOrders` will be inserted to the database with their `JobId` set appropriately.
- EF will find out what their IDs are
- `myTools` and `myToolHoles` will be inserted with the `HoleId` and `OrderId` set with the values found in the second step.

Comment: of course you can also wrap your code in a `using`, and use `BeginTransaction()`, `Commit()`, and `Rollback()`.

Comment: So I need to map the tools/toolholes to both Holes and Orders? I was trying that before and was getting an error about conflicting changes being detected.

Comment: How are they associated now then?

Comment: I found that I am not mapping to Holes correctly. I was adding them the same way I was adding to Orders and that's incorrect. Thank you for the help. Hopefully I can get it working this this knowledge.